# How User should be prevented to input other languages except selected one in java

Tags: java, string, validation

How to prevent a user from inputing different langauge character.Suppose if a user is running in english mode then validation should run against all different languages and only engish character should be allowed for input.

Using this appraoch i have to check all  regularExpression Of unicode for all language.

```
loop for  user input{
   userinputString.matches("someregex Of unicode for different language ");
}
```

**Is there some better way to do this? How User should be prevented to input other langauges ?**

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/language-detection/

Comment: What if somebody with for example Gujarati setting, wants to write "Apple iPhone"? I don't think that this is a useful feature. I would **hate** to use a website like that!